# Fundamental solution of the frozen opearator

Tags: differential-operators, fundamental-solution

Let $L$ be some differential operator of the form
$$
Ly = y^{(n)}(x) + a_{n-1}(x) y^{(n-1)}(x) + \dots + a_0(x) y(x)
$$
with all $a_k(x)$ being smooth.

Let also $M$ be the frozen at $x=0$ operator $L$ (note that $M$ has constant coefficients):
$$
My = y^{(n)}(x) + a_{n-1}(0) y^{(n-1)}(x) + \dots + a_0(0) y(x).
$$
Consider also fundamental solution $u$ of the operator $M$, i.e.
$$
Mu = \delta(x).
$$
Is that true that
$$
Lu - \delta(x)
$$
is a smooth function? In other words, does $Lu$ have singularity only at $x = 0$?

**My approach**: Let $y$ be the fundamental solution of $L$. Assume that it has a form 
$$
y(x) = P(x) \theta(x).
$$
Then
$$
Ly = L[P\theta]\\
L[P\theta] = \sum_{k=0}^n a_k(x) \frac{d^k}{dx^k}\left[P(x)\theta(x)\right] = \sum_{k=0}^n a_k(x)
\sum_{m=0}^k {k \choose m} P^{(k-m)}(x) \theta^{(m)}(x) = \\
= \sum_{m=0}^n \left(\sum_{k=m}^n{k \choose m}
a_k(x) P^{(k-m)}(x)
\right) \theta^{(m)}(x) = \\
= \left(\sum_{k=0}^n
a_k(x) P^{(k)}(x)
\right) \theta(x)
+ \sum_{m=0}^{n-1} \left(\sum_{k=m+1}^n
{k \choose m+1}
a_k(x) P^{(k-m-1)}(x)
\right) \delta^{(m)}(x).
$$
Using the fact
$$
a(x) \delta^{(m)}(x) = \sum_{k=0}^m {m \choose k} (-1)^k a^{(k)}(0) \delta^{(m-k)}(x)
$$
the last term in $L[P\theta]$  can be brought to form
$$
L[P\theta] = L[P]\theta + \sum_{m=0}^{n-1}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \alpha_{m,k} P^{(k)}(0) \delta^{(m)}(x)
$$
so we've got a Cauchy problem for $P(x)$:
$$
LP = 0\\
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \alpha_{m,k} P^{(k)}(0) = \begin{cases}
1, &m = 0\\
0, &m \neq 0\end{cases}.
$$
Freezing $L$ keeps $L[P]$ value at $x = 0$, so $M[P]\theta(x)$ remains smooth, but the singluar part seems to be altered completely, since $\alpha_{m,k}$ depend on $a_k(x)$ derivatives at $x = 0$ (and I don't see a reason why should they not). But it appears that freezing derivatives of $a_k(x)$ up to $n - k - 1$ orders leaves the $\alpha_{m,k}$ the same, so the $Mu-\delta = M[P]\theta$ is a smooth function.

This proof is complicated and I might be missing something. Also I have a feeling that the Cauchy problem for $P$ can be expressed much simpler, without nesting four sumations.